# copy resources with output path containing part of input path

Tags: maven, maven-resources-plugin

Say two modules `mod1` and `mod2` have the following structure:

```
root
├── mod1/src/main/resources/db-migrations
|   ├── v1
|   |   ├── a.sql
|   |   └── b.sql
|   └── v2
|       ├── c.sql
|       └── d.sql
|
└── mod2/src/main/resources/db-migrations
    ├── v1
    |   ├── e.sql
    |   └── f.sql
    └── v2
        ├── g.sql
        └── h.sql
```

I want to copy all files from `db-migrations` into a single top-level directory, but grouped by version first, and by module second. So the output should look like this:

```
root/all-db-migrations
├── v1
|   ├── mod1
|   |   ├── a.sql
|   |   └── b.sql
|   └── mod2
|       ├── e.sql
|       └── f.sql
└── v2
    ├── mod1
    |   ├── c.sql
    |   └── d.sql
    └── mod2
        ├── g.sql
        └── h.sql
```

If the directory structure wasn't inversed (module name before version), this is easy with the maven resource plugin by just copying the entire `db-migrations` directory for each module:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-database-migrations</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>../all-db-migrations/${project.artifactId}
                </outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources/db-migrations</directory>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However, I could not find a solution to do such a copy operation as described above.

Comment: Have you taken a look at flyway / liquibase which handle such things ?

Comment: We do use flyway too, but we also need to copy the patches into the described structure to feed another db migration tool that's also in production use

Comment: Hm..why using tow different tools? Furthermore I strongly discourage to copy something in `src/..` folders during the build cause those directories are under version control etc...bad idea...